# how can I schedule a something to run every day, every two days, every three days from start date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scheduled-tasks

I have to send notifications from server. Their triggering time is dynamic and not same for every notificaation. For every notification it has attached triggering time.
eg.

```
notification_id  start_date   end_date      time   recurring_time
    1            2016-06-06    2016-06-20   12-pm  every_1_day
    2            2016-06-06    2016-06-20   4-pm   every_2_day
    3            2016-06-06    2016-06-20   1-am   every_2_week
    4            2016-06-06    2016-06-20   3-pm   every_month
```

I was thinking about using `whenever gem` but it also need to have a specific time of day like `every 1.hour do`

how can i check every day that i need to run task that is every_2_day or every_7_day from starting date.

Comment: [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) can handle your recurring events. I've used the gem extensively, and it's solid.

Comment: @MarsAtomic this gem seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

**Using whenever gem**

## In rails 4

```
    require File.expand_path('../..//config/environment.rb', __FILE__)

# This is your table by which you will get your new value 

    bid_update = DynamicOfferTime.first

# Now Task As

    every (bid_update.hour_value).hours do
      puts "This will repeat in every #{bid_update.hour_value} hour"
    end
```

Now make a another rake task, which will update DynamicOfferTime.first value before start your main cron job.